# Learning OOP - distributing logic and dividing responsibility

Tags: php, class, oop, constructor

Trying to move from global procedural coding to a more OOP-oriented style, I'm refactoring a website for a magazine.

One of the conditions to check on the server is whether an article id or a combination of year/issue has been passed in. In the first case the user should be served a specific article, in the second case the table of contents and the image cover for the selected issue. I also need to retrieve the year and issue for display purposes in the second case.

My first instinct was to put all the the logic inside the constructor:

```
class Magazine {
    public $year;
    public $issue;
    public function __construct($year, $issue, $articleId = 0) {
        if($articleId > 0) {
            // Get article from database
            $this->year = // get year from search results;
            $this->issue = // get number from search results;
        } else {
            // Get table of contents and cover image
        }
    }
}

// Create an instance either like this:
$magazine = new Magazine(1985, 3);
// Or like this:
$magazine = new Magazine(0, 0, 172);
```

But then I realized that it's probably not a good idea to "overload" the constructor in this way (to compensate for not being able to overload it in the usual sense?).

Ok, so I create a method for retrieving the article, like so:

```
class Magazine {
    public $year;
    public $issue;
    private $articleId;
    public function __construct($year, $issue, $articleId = 0) {
        $this->year = $year;
        $this->issue = $issue;
        $this->articleId = $articleId;
    }
    public function getArticle() {
        // Use $this->articleId to retrieve data from database
        // Set $this->year and $this->issue to appropriate values
    }
}
```

Or without a constructor:

```
class Magazine {
    public $year;
    public $issue;
    public function getArticle($articleId) {
        // Use $articleId to retrieve data from database
        // Set $this->year and $this->issue to appropriate values
    }
}
```

No, assigning values to the year and issue properties is not part of getting an article. So I create another method for that:

```
public function getYearAndIssue($articleId) {
    // Use $articleId to retrieve data from database
}
```

But now I need to connect to the database twice. Not good. It seems like I have to collect all the data I need when connecting to the db the first time. And where do I do that? In the constructor? No, that will just take me back to square one. Or minus one.

So where do I go from here? Two methods like  `getArticleAndEverythingElseINeedForThat() { // ... }` and `getCoverAndEverythingElseINeedForThat() { ... }`?

**EDIT:** Thanks to Daan’s comment I've experimented some more and come up with the following:

```
class Magazine {
    private $db;
    public function __construct($db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }
    public function getArticle($articleId) {
        $sql = "SELECT article FROM table WHERE id = :id";
        $ph = array(':id' => $articleId);
        $ps = $this->db -> prepare($sql); 
        $ps -> execute($ph);
        // Do some more stuff
        return $article;
    }
    public function getYearAndIssue($articleId) {
        $sql = "SELECT year, issue FROM table WHERE id = :id";
        $ph = array(':id' => $articleId);
        ...
        return array($year, $issue);
    }
}

class Database {
    public static function getConnection() {
        $db = new PDO(...);
        $db->setAttribute(...);
        ...
        return $db;
    }
}

$db = Database::getConnetion();
$magazine = new Magazine($db);
$article = $magazine->getArticle(59);
list($year, $issue) = $magazine->getYearAndIssue(59);
```

New questions:

Do I seem close to understand injection?

In some descriptions I've seen the PDO object is created both as a private variable in the constructor and passed as an argument to the helper functions, i.e. as if I'd written my code like this:

```
class Magazine {
    private $db;
    public function __construct($db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }
    public function getArticle($db, $articleId) {
        // ...
    }
}
$db = Database::getConnetion();
$magazine = new Magazine($db);
$article = $magazine->getArticle($db, 59);
```

Should I do that too? If so, why?

Even if I use the same db connection twice (or more times in the real scenario), I still have to get stuff from the db several times. Wouldn't it be better/faster to get everything I need from the db at once (if it would be possible without messing up the logic again/any further)? Like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT article, year, issue FROM table WHERE id = :id";
```

Comment: Inject your connection variable in the constructor and put in a private class variable that way you only have one connection.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure I understand exactly what you suggest, but I made an attempt to interpret your comment which resulted in the above edit. :)

Comment: Thats exactly what I meant well done.

Comment: On the other hand, the connection variable is still declared globally. Why would that be ok in this case?